# xPath for javascript

Tags: javascript, xpath

I have this javascript code in html

```
<script type="text/javascript">function initialize() {
    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(50.475816506586240, 30.496437549591064);
    var myOptions = {zoom: 16, center: latlng, draggable: false, mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,scrollwheel: false};
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googlePlaceMap"), myOptions);
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({position: latlng, title: "Сквер"});
    marker.setMap(map);
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", initialize);
</script>
```

I am trying to parse it to get latitude and longitude (lat = 50.475..., lng = 30.496...) using xPath but I can't. Could you help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a combination of [`substring-before`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Functions/substring-before) and [`substring-after`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Functions/substring-after) functions:

```
substring-before(substring-after(//script/text(), "google.maps.LatLng("), ");")
```

This would give you the following output:

```
50.475816506586240, 30.496437549591064
```